# Tabs to navigate page by page

Tags: php, jquery, sql, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I use bootstrap with JQuery and I would like to use tabs to navigate page by page.

Indeed, I have some results in a table. With SQL, I know how to do this by using LIMITE 1,10 for example. And by using a $_GET argument to navigate page by page...

But here, I would like use tabs instead.

Here is my code:

```
echo '<div class="tab-content">';
echo '<div class="tab-pane fade in active" id=1>';

while($row = $selectAllUsersM->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){

$isActive = ($row->Activation) ? 'Desable' : 'Enable';

echo "<tr>";                                                echo '<td>'.$row->Firstname.'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$row->Name.'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$row->Nickname.'</td>';
echo '<td><a href="mailto:'.$row->Email.'">'.$row->Email.'</a></td>';
echo '<td>'.timeToDDMMYYYY($row->DateInscription).'</td>';
echo '<td><a href="?param='.$row->Activation.'&id='.$row->IdUser.'" title='.$isActive.'>'.isActive($row->Activation).'</a></td>';

echo "</tr>";

}

echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
```

Here is the example for pagination:

```
<ul class="pagination">
  <li><a href="#1">&laquo;</a></li>
  <li><a href="#2">1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#3">2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#4">3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#5">4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#6">5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#7">&raquo;</a></li>
</ul>
```

I don't know how can I display 10 results on each page. Then, if 11 results, create a new page and a new tab. I hope you know what I mean.

Thank you for your help ;)

Comment: This feels like three questions in one, can you narrow down your issue?

Comment: Ok. Well, how can I generate tabs with pagination from results of sql request, 10 results by tab. So, if i have 42 results => 5 tabs. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I solved this by using a POST in Ajax.

Function to display results

```
<script>
    function displayPilotesF(pageF) { 

      $.post("pilotesF.php",
       { page : pageF},
       function(data){
        //alert("Data Loaded: " +  data);
        $("#pilotesF").html(data); 
       }
      );
    }
</script>
```

I display the results in a div:

```
<div id="pilotesF"></div>
```

And on my page "pilotesF.php":

```
if(isset($_POST['page'])){

   $page = $_POST['page'];

   $selectAllUsersF= getAllInfoOfAllUsersF($page, nbPiloteFPerPage);
   $selectAllUsersF->execute();

   echo "<table class='table table-hover table-condensed'>";
    echo "<th>Firstname</th>";
    echo "<th>Name</th>";
    echo "<th>Nickname</th>";
    echo "<th>Email</th>";
    echo "<th>Registration</th>";
    echo "<th>State account</th>";

    while($row = $selectAllUsersF->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){

     $isActive = ($row->Activation) ? 'Disable' : 'Enable';

     echo "<tr>";
        echo '<td>'.$row->Firstname.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row->Name.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row->Nickname.'</td>';
        echo '<td><a href="mailto:'.$row->Email.'">'.$row->Email.'</a></td>';
        echo '<td>'.timeToDDMMYYYY($row->DateInscription).'</td>';
        echo '<td><a href="?param='.$row->Activation.'&id='.$row->IdUser.'" title='.$isActive.'>'.isActive($row->Activation).'</a></td>';
     echo "</tr>";

    }

   echo "</table>";             
}
```

And for my pagination:

```
$nbPages= ceil($nbPiloteF/ nbPiloteFPerPage);

echo '<div class="text-center">';
  echo '<ul class="pagination" id="tabs2">';

/***********************************/

for ($i = 1 ; $i <= $nbPages; $i++){

if($i == 1)
   echo '<li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" OnClick="displayPilotesF('.$i.');">'.$i.'</a></li>';                                               
else
  echo '<li><a data-toggle="tab" OnClick="displayPilotesF('.$i.');">'.$i.'</a></li>';

}

/***********************************/
   echo '</ul>';
echo '</div>';
```

Maybe it could help some of you guys,
Thank you anyway, have a night! :)